# Straight Edges Curved After Triangulation OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a project using openCV to create a 3D image from 2D images. Currently I am just working with 2 Images to simplify things.

What I am confused about is that currently my 4D triangulated points appear to make some sense with my point matches. Despite this there are some points which are on straight surfaces which are being mapped onto curved lines. Is there a reason for this? I assume it could potentially be because the object at these points is relatively far away from the camera which I imagine would degrade the precision of the image. Is this intuition correct, and if I take more images will this problem alleviate itself eventually? What is also interesting is that when I reproject the 4D points back to 3D they are no longer curved.

Below are my images showing, coordinate axis, matched points, 4D reconstruction, and then re-projected 3D results

[image: Left Camera Image with Coordinate Axes]
[image: Right Camera Image with Coordinate Axes]
[image: Matched Points Between Images]
[image: Triangulated 3D Points]

The 3D Triangulated Points make some sense to me. My guess is that the curved surface is the front of the fish tank The blob which is almost along the negative x-axis and has negative z-coordinates is from the bottle. The rest of the points appear to be from the checkerboard grid/noise.

Comment: Did you rectify images for undistorting?

Comment: @Nikita Yes I used cv.undistortPoints() to remove distortion from the images prior to triangulation

Comment: Oh, Got it. Do you want to build the navigation system?